# Send Partial Page as File Attachment via Email Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

Is it possible to send a partial page, say content of an IFrame or Content of a Panel as an attachment in an Email?

I am dynamically creating manufacturing drawing pages with dynamic dimensioning. I'd like the user to be able to click an Email button and send it as attachment to the vendor.

Comment: So you want to attach .htm  files to an e-mail, and send them? "manufacturing drawing pages" sounds a bit like you would want to send image files.

Comment: Well I also have labels and tables that surround the image and dipslays corresponding dimensional data. That data is dynaically updated upon user selections.

Comment: Then i need to turn all that into a file and send to vendor when user clicks the send button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Server.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.execute.aspx) to execute a page, capture the output in your TextWriter, and then use that string to build an html attachment for your e-mail. The server.execute is still executed in the current user context, so if you put their selections in the Session or so, it´s easy enough to build the nexessary html. There are some pitfalls though:

- If you´re linking to images and using hrefs, either make those absolute links  or use a base href tag in your head
- I´d beware of sending html attachments: spam filters and virus scanners could block them.

Good luck!

Menno

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer. I will try that. I also have a pdf creator by winnovative (haven't tried yet). I'm wondering if i can save the pdf to the server and then send as attachment. Would that work?

Comment: Do you mean the winnovative html to pdf converter? I´ve used that one, and it has worked great for me. 
Basically you would take the html (you still need the base href), and feed it straight into the pdf generator. You probably don´t ever need to save to the hard drive: I think you can save straight to a (memory)stream, and then use the stream for your attachment.

Comment: Yes,  winnovative html to pdf converter is what i have. Haven't used it yet successfully. You wouldn't happen to have a snippet of code would ya? That would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert.PdfConverter p = new Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert.PdfConverter();

            p.LicenseKey = "NotPostingTHat";
            p.PdfDocumentOptions.GenerateSelectablePdf = true;
            /*
            ... Setting a bunch of options ...
            */
            p.PdfFooterOptions.DrawFooterLine = false;

            System.IO.TextWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();

            string html = "";
            string pdfType = GetPdfType();

            switch (pdfType.ToUpper())
            {
                case "THEME":
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("~/Pdf/Theme.aspx", writer);
                    break;
                /* More cases */
            }

            html = writer.ToString();

            if (html.Length > 0)
            {
                byte[] bytes = p.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(html);
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("No data found!");

                foreach (string item in context.Request.Form.AllKeys)
                    context.Response.Write(String.Format("{0}: {1}\n", new object[] { item, context.Request.Form[item] }));
            }
```

Nothing to it. This was in an .ashx.

Menno

Comment: Thank you again. I will definately incorporate this into my web app.